# Appcelerator Studio stuck after opening on mac

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-studio

I am trying to setup Android SDK on Appcelerator Studio.After opening appcelerator studio it gets stuck and nothing happens after that.

I have checked appcelerator studio log it shows error:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-05 15:05:05.353
>   !MESSAGE Application error
>   !STACK 1
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp.application" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: com.aptana.commandline.launcher.LauncherApplication, org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.GenTopic, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.InstallPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.EclipseGenerator, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.ProductPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.repo2runnable, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.metadataverifier, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.CategoryPublisher, org.eclipse.help.base.infocenterApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.helpApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.indexTool, org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench.
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the Java version which you're using? Make sure you're running on JDK 1.8.131

Comment: Can you also start with the new workspace and see